# How to set a readonly property with typescript in componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I would like to have constant (readonly) properties in a React.Component class. The problem is that I should not initialize them in the constructor since they trigger side effects like setInterval or fetch. Instead I should initialize them in componentDidMount but since I use strict type checkings I must also indicate their types can be undefined (or null, whatsoever). That's what I want to avoid because then I am forced to check if the value is not null every time I use it despite I know it already, and I also wanna avoid using the "!" operator as much as possible because then I don't have type errors when I forget to initialize them.

Does there exist a clean solution? Some way to tell typescript that componentDidMount is like a constructor and so a property can be initialized only there?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no clean way to do this. It's inherent to TypeScript's understanding of classes that there are roughly two areas of the class *(ignoring errata not relevant to the question)*:

- The constructor: where fields -and their backing types- are being initialized
- The rest of the class: where fields are being used - and their backing types don't change

Taking a step back: knowing that `componentDidMount` is an initialization function is something like a "hidden assumption" in code. That is, it's not a part of JavaScript itself and nothing in the code itself explains it. It's something you're expected to know when working with React classes. The type system not having a good tool for this is because it'd be very difficult to describe in type-system-land the nuances of each framework's magic.

Having to memorize these hidden assumptions is part of why many developers have moved to [React function components](https://react.dev/learn/your-first-component). They don't have a need to mutate the types of properties over time - it's more around variables and scoping, which fit better into type systems.